# After calculating date field validation error in Infopath Designer

Tags: infopath, infopath2010, date-arithmetic

I am trying to do a calculation where the date always gets calculated to the 30th of a month so, I am using this formula in a text box,

```
concat(substring(Calculated Cal. Due Date, 7, 1), "/30/", substring(Calculated Cal. Due Date, 1, 4))
```

Then I created a Date picker box and in it's default value, I made it equal to the text box, however I am receiving a validation error where it is showing red dashes around the `Date Picker` box. Also when a calculation is made, it is in the correct format , `mm/dd/yyyy`. Even with the consistent formatting, there is a red dash , showing a validation error. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

I am still trying everything, but to no avail :(

Comment: What are the current validation rules on the Date box?

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I had to use the concat function to match 2015-11-05T00:00:00

Comment: Oh nice. lol. I already posted and answer since I didn't see this >.<

Answer (score 0):

### Instructions

1. Add a rule to your DatePicker field that has no condition.
2. Add the `Set a field's value` action to your rule.
3. Select the DatePicker as the field you'd like to set (should be default)
4. Set the following formula as the value to which you're setting the field:

   ```
   concat(substring(string(.), 1, 4), "-", substring(string(.), 6, 2), "-28")
   ```

### Explanation

If you convert the value of a DatePicker box to a string by using `string(dateBox)`, the result will be in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd`

This is not what is displayed in the DatePicker box, but it is the underlying string. Knowing this, you can use a similar method to extract the parts of the date you want.

I created a DatePicker box that uses a rule to calculate its value, meaning it is calculated every time the date is changed. The result is that every time a date is selected, it is automatically bumped to the 30th.

**NOTE**: entering `2015-02-30` will cause a validation error in the date box as well since February only has 28 or 29 days, of course. The snippet I've entered above will solve the problem universally for the 28th of every month. More logic would have to go into detecting the month of the selected date if you really want to allow the 30th of every month *but* February, and then have special case for that.